# How can I create a triangle div with CSS which will disappear when clicked but not when the 'overflow' part is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This answer on a different thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808936/6401041 says that this method for creating a CSS triangle is good because you can 'trigger the hover state or **click event** only when the cursor is inside the triangle' and then a demo is shown for how this can be done with the hover state.

My problem is basically this one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIS7.png

I don't want the user to be able to click in that area and trigger my onclick function which makes my triangle disappear. I have seen how to do this with :hover and :active but not with a **click event**. How can I make it so that only when the user clicks inside the triangle, does the function get called, making the triangle disappear for good with

```
style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You need to add a code sample for other users who need help. If that link becomes invalid people won't be able to solve their own related problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the triangle with a `div`element, instead of a pseudoelement.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/Lbdm5paq/5/)

```js
document.querySelector('.triangle').onclick = function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.triangle-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100px;
}

.triangle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0079C6;
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle-container">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: woah thanks. But I have been doing it with a div until now... I see you've used a container though. And you've used jquery or something?  Am I able to do the same thing as 'document.querySelector('') with

    document.getElementById("");

?

Comment: I've used javascript. You can give the container an Id and target it with `getElementById` instead. --> https://jsfiddle.net/uqh1mh5n/1/

Comment: Edit, meant you can give the triangle an id!

Comment: Wow! Nice! Thank you. And do you need the container?

Comment: Yes. Because you need overflow hidden to create the triangle effect.